# Weird encoding of white spaces PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have this seemingly normal string (not stored in a DB) along with many similar ones like this:

```
2　40,802　40,802　Nanatsu no Taizai OP “Seven Deadly Sins”
```

And I'm trying to extract data out of it, unfortunately, explode or any PHP functions didn't seem to be working correctly and I echo'd it to find out why:

```
echo $string;    
Output: 2ã€€40,802ã€€40,802ã€€Nanatsu no Taizai OP â€œSeven Deadly Sinsâ€
echo utf8_decode($string);
Output:  2?40,802?40,802?Nanatsu no Taizai OP ?Seven Deadly Sins?
```

html_entity_decode does not change anything and explode('?', $string); after uft8_decode returns an empty array. How do I get my string the way back to normal without Euro currencies and '?' characters everywhere and why are they showing up in the first place?

Comment: Was this information stored in a DB? If it was then the reason why is because of the character encoding set for that table in the DB.

Comment: No, I just copied some text from a site

Comment: What is the charset on your HTML doc?

Comment: http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1354310 copied fine for me

Comment: It copies fun and when I paste it in my code editor, it's fine. But when I echo it out like this:

$string = <<EOD
*2.　40,802　*40,802　Nanatsu no Taizai OP "Seven Deadly Sins" by MAN WITH A MISSION" EOD;
echo $string;
It outputs that weird character encoding, and explode nor str_replace or most PHP functions do anything to it

Comment: well it's something you)your software) is doing, can't reproduce so can't help

Comment: I found a weird fix. Added this: header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```